# return data based on the fetch urls

Tags: observable, rxjs6

I was trying to get the fetched data based on the changed events. The result I was expected should be an object instead I see observable as the fetch produces promise.

The `flatMap` was used to convert `promise` to an object, but it seems I was doing wrong. Please let me know how I can fix it.

```
/** Receives UpdateEvent */
const changes$ = new Subject<FileChangesEvent>();

/** mock for 'this' */
const context = {
    notify: (...args) => console.log('[CONTEXT.NOTIFY]: ', ...args),
    processAdds: (input) => of(input).pipe(delay(input.debounce || 1), map(i => Object.assign(i, ...fetch(i.url)))),
    processUpdates: (input) => of(input).pipe(delay(input.debounce || 1), map(i => Object.assign(i, ...fetch(i.url)))),
    processDeletes: (input) => of(input).pipe(delay(input.debounce || 1), map(i => Object.assign(i, { modified: 'fetchUpdates' }))),
};

/** Process FilesChange event */
const stream$ = changes$
    .pipe(
        /** Side effect for log current step */
        tap(event => console.log('onFileChanges trigged, event data: ', event.changes)),
        /** Fetching array of changes */
        map(event => event.changes),
        /** Use it for wait all 'forked' observables */
        flatMap(
            /** Process each record in parallel */
            changes => forkJoin(
                changes.map(change =>
                    /** Update processing */
                    of(change)
                        .pipe(
                            tap(input => console.log('Validating the file Type: ', input)),
                            /** fetching data based on update type */
                            flatMap(input =>
                                input.type === FileChangeType.ADDED
                                    ? context.processAdds(input)
                                    : context.processUpdates(input),
                            ),
                            /** remove large files from update */
                            map(input => (
                                input.type === FileChangeType.UPDATED && input.size < CONTENT_SIZE_LIMIT
                                    ? Object.assign(input, { value: '' })
                                    : input
                            )),
                            /** side effect for pubsub notifications */
                            tap(updates => context.notify(updates)),
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

/** When updates stream was finished */
stream$.subscribe(
    (...args) => console.log('[TICK]: ', ...args), // When all event updates was processed
    (...args) => console.log('[ERROR]: ', ...args),
    (...args) => console.log('[DONE]: ', ...args),
);

export const updateEventsStream = (event) => changes$.next(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code. First is destructuring a promise - `map(i => Object.assign(i, ...fetch(i.url)))`. It destroys it completely and you will not be able to get a result out of it. If you need to modify the value returned from api use `then`: `map(i => fetch(i.url).then(val => Object.assign(i, ...val)))`.

Ok, next problem exactly with observables. You are correctly using `flatMap` to unwrap value returned from `processAdds` (and others), but the fact is these functions return promise wrapped in observable. You start with creating observable out of input: `of(input)` and then `map` input to promise. Hence when you unwrap result in `flatMap` you get promise not it's value.

Simple solution would be to unwrap promise inside helper functions using any `<something>Map` operators, e.g. the same `flatMap`:

```
processAdds: (input) =>
  of(input).pipe(delay(input.debounce || 1), flatMap(i => fetch(i.url))),
```

You can check full example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fetch-flatmap?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: How does `flatMap` forward the error when the fetch fails with some error?

Comment: It passes it down the stream. Example of replacing `fetch` with `Promise.reject` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iorier

Comment: I mean i don't want to fail the stack when we get the error. I rather want to continue by assign error to another observable and collect errors by manually by filtering with a type set before when it got failed.

Comment: Please ask another question with more details and code samples

Comment: @user1595858 If I answer your original question please accept the answer